# HTML5 video issue in Chrome when loaded via JavaScript (large files only)

Tags: javascript, html, video, large-files

I'm running into a very specific issue with  in Chrome / Desktop Safari.

The video doesn't load at all when I inject it onto the page using JavaScript. It's not a markup issue, nor is it a MIME type issue, since I can confirm the video is loading when it's a static element on the page (I'm loading this video with Ajax).

It seems to have to do with the filesize, since it works just fine with a smaller video in all browsers. It only occurs when I'm trying to stream a much larger video.

The approach works completely fine in Firefox / IE9, just not in Chrome / Desktop Safari.

Here's the markup I'm using, and I can confirm the correct MIME type declarations are in my .htaccess.

```
  <video autoplay controls class="main-video">
    <source src="/videos/Miranda.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
    <source src="/videos/Miranda.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
    <source src="/videos/Miranda.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />

    <p>
    Sorry, there was a problem playing this video
    </p>
  </video>
```

Comment: You should share the method your using to inject the markup into the HTML document. You may want to try using something like window.open("").document.write(htmlVideoTag) and see if that results in the same issue.